# Testing with JMeter:How to simulate load in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to conduct load testing for an application based on the below scenario:

No of stores: 1307

No of users: 1307 x 4 = 5228

Average transactions per day per store: 5 transactions

Total transaction per month for all stores: 1307 x 5 x 30 = 196,050

What will be the virtual users required??and how to simuate it in JMETER .

Answer (score 0):

196050 / 30 (days in month) / 24 (hours in day) / 60 (minutes in hour) = 4.5 requests per minute.

It means 1 request each 13 seconds. I don't think that you even need JMeter to produce such a "load".

If you do - consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer), it allows to specify target throughput in "requests per minute".

There is more advanced version available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project - [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which is more precise, acts on "seconds" level and provides options to set stepping ramp-up and ramp-down load.